# Problem in the proof of root 2 is irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers

The standard way we prove that the square root of $2$ is irrational is the following:

Let us assume the square root of $2$ is rational and is equal to $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are co-prime.

∴$\sqrt{2} = \frac{a}{b}  \Rightarrow 2=\frac{a^2}{b^2}\Rightarrow b^2 = \frac{a^2}{2}$

∴ $a^2$ is divisible by $2$

∴ $a$ is divisible by $2$

I want to stop here. How does the statement **$a^2$ is divisible by $2$** imply **$a$ is divisible by $2$**? For example, $4$ is divisible by $4$, but that does not mean $2$ is divisible by $4$.

Comment: $2$ is prime!!!

Comment: Without knowing any arithmetic, you can also prove easily that a number is even iff its square is even.

Comment: See [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).   The special case $p=2$ can easily be proven on its own.

Comment: With regards to the "special case proven on its own"... if you suppose $a$ were *not* divisible by $2$, i.e. that $a$ is odd, then it would follow that $a^2$ were also odd.  This proof is classic for a reason.  Make sure you understand it well.

Comment: @NikitaArtemenko I have taken the liberty to rollback your changes. Replacing $\sqrt{2}$ by $√2$ and $\Rightarrow$ by $=>$ is *not* an improvement, quite the contrary.

Comment: @MartinR, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An even square must be even. To see this note that $(2k)^2=2(2k^2)$ which is even. An odd number squared is $(2k+1)^2 = 4k^2+4k +1 = 2(2k^2+2k) + 1$ which is odd. Since all integers are either even or odd this accounts for all squares which can be verified by considering their remainder when divided by $2$.

Comment: @hardmath sure, I added it.